# OpenCL fake bitfield

Tags: programming-languages, opencl, parallel-processing, bit-fields, gpu

Is it possible AT ALL? I know that OpenCL doesn't support normal bitfields right now.

Could there be a way to get a definite 64-bits out of bool myBool[64] or something like

```
union newType{
    double value;
    bool bit[64];
};
```

or anything at all remotely related that could be helpful? i'ld like to have some static bit patterns to compare against value and be able to quickly manipulate single bits of the patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenCL Spec guarantees that a `double` will be 64 bits and that you can reinterpret it using `as_long()` or a union to get a `long`, which is 64 bits.

Reinterpreting a 64 bit scalar to something like a `char[8]` or a `char8` is legal (using a union and `as_char8()` respectively), but the result is implementation-defined. Things like endianness conversions may occur, so you may have to watch out if your GPU behaves differently from your CPU in that respect.

The only portable way to do bit manipulation on a `double` is to use bitwise operators on a 64-bit scalar integer type, meaining `long` or `ulong`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Use binary operators on a 64 bit int, Not sure if 64 bit ints are valid, so just make a struct with 2 ints and mask and shift as desired.

I suggest you investigate the operators `&` `|` `^` `~`

Comment: awesome thank you! will a 

struct myStruct{
char[8];
}

work as well?

Comment: yes, but beware of endedness issues and @user57368 states in his/her answer

Comment: maybe i could have a little endian kernel and a big endian kernel version based on application's initialization phase or something, thanks again!

Comment: I believe there are #defines for ended_ness. At the very least I know you can check endedness of the device.